# Rails migration create_join_table with uuids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Newer versions of rails let you specify that tables should be created with a uuid primary key like so:

```
create_table :foos, id: :uuid do |t|
  # ...
end
```

Which is great.  And for a long time rails has supported creating join tables like so:

```
create_join_table :foos, :bars do |t|
  # ...
end
```

Also great.  Except my tables have uuid primary keys and that generates foreign key columns of type integer instead of type uuid.

Looking over [the documentation for `create_join_table`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/create_join_table), I can't find anything obvious to change the column type.  Is it possible to use `create_join_table` with uuids?

Or do I have create the join table manually:

```
create_table :bars_foos, id: false do |t|
  t.uuid :bar_id
  t.uuid :foo_id
end
```

Answer (score 13):

Within `Rails 5.0` you can use an additional option `column_options` on the `create_join_table` method to specify the type of your id columns. Your migration would then look like:

```
create_join_table :foos, :bars, column_options: {type: :uuid} do |t|
  t.index [:foo_id, :baar_id]
end
```

Comment: Confirmed working with Rails 7 

Answer (score 8):

There is no way of creating join tables with uuids.

As pointed out in the question `create_table` is the only option. The best way of emulating `create_join_tables` with uuid is by using `create_tables` as follows:

- Run: `rails g migration CreateFoosBars bars:references foos:references`
- The command will produce the following output which you will need to modify

generate output

```
class CreateBarFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bars_foos, id: :uuid do |t|
      t.references :bars, foreign_key: true
      t.references :foo, foreign_key: true
    end
  end
end
```

- Change `id: uuid` => `id: false`
- Add `type: uuid, index: true` to the end of the references

final migration

```
class CreateBarFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :bars_foos, id: false do |t|
      t.references :bars, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid, index: true
      t.references :foo, foreign_key: true, type: :uuid, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

It would be good if Rails could add extra support for different id types in  `create_join_table`, this could even be inferred by an existing migration.

Until then hopefully these steps will achieve the same result.

Comment: This is the right answer for the given version of Rails (4.2.x), and @anka's answer is correct for version 5 and up.

Answer (score 5):

I should have looked at the code...

```
def create_join_table(table_1, table_2, options = {})
  join_table_name = find_join_table_name(table_1, table_2, options)

  column_options = options.delete(:column_options) || {}
  column_options.reverse_merge!(null: false)

  t1_column, t2_column = [table_1, table_2].map{ |t| t.to_s.singularize.foreign_key }

  create_table(join_table_name, options.merge!(id: false)) do |td|
    td.integer t1_column, column_options
    td.integer t2_column, column_options
    yield td if block_given?
  end
end
```

Columns are explicitly created as integers with no means to change them.  Too bad...